# ¿Por que el css solo se muestra en una pagina y no en otras en laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel

Hola tengo un problema estoy tratando de aprender laravel y me eh topado con esto resulta que en web.php donde manejo las rutas eh colocado este pequeño codigo

```
Route::get('/tarea-listar',[TareasController::class,'create'])->name("tareas.create");
```

en el controlador tengo

```
 public function create()
    {
        return view("tareas.list");
    }
```

hasta ahi todo bien ya que al ir al buscador e ingresar localhost/tareas/public/tarea-listar se muestra la vista normalmente

ahora quize mostrar la misma vista pero cambiando un poco la ruta en este caso asi

```
Route::get('/tarea/listar',[TareasController::class,'create'])->name("tareas.create");
```

pero nada al ingresar a la url localhost/tareas/public/tarea/listar se abre pero no cargan los estilos ni archivos js ¿No entiendo que esta mal? cabe mencionar que si estoy haciendo uso de rutas absolutas para el css y js

```
<link href="{{ asset('/assets/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Resumiendo si accedo a una ruta sin niveles me carga bien estos archivos pero si hago una ruta con 2 niveles tipo http://localhost/tareas/public/tarea/listar no cargan estos archivos. No se que podría estar mal.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que ejecutes tu proyecto con el live server que trae laravel para evitar estos tipos de inconvenientes. Abres la consola de comandos y te diriges a tu carpeta del proyecto y ejecutas "php artisan serve" y con eso se ejecutará el live server. Ahora solo tienes que dirigirte a la ruta que te muestra la consola, por lo regultar es http://localhost:8000 y así ya puedes dirigirte a tu ruta http://localhost:8000/tarea/lista

Comment: hola si ya lo habia hecho, pero no sigo con ese problema.